# Варианты реализации UI

Tags: wpf, gui, ui, design, usercontrol

Всем привет. Такой вопрос, как лучше (критерии : правильность, быстрота во время работы программы) делать UI(CheckBox, ProgressBar, ScrollBar, TabControl) как на картинке ниже? Я имею в виду что лучше : создать просто пользовательский контрол и напихать на него анимации? или сделать на каждый тип контрола свой style? но я вот не знаю насчёт создания к каждому своего style, ведь style изменяет только стандартные параметры типа : Font, margin, padding и т.д. тем более я не знаю как крепить анимацию к style. А вот насчёт создания пользовательского контрола, то обидно что нет импорта загатовок из photoshop как это было в старых версиях VisualStudio и придётся попыхтеть. Посоветуйте пожалуйста как лучше сделать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `<Style/>` у большинства элементов управления можно также определить `<ControlTamplate/>` и там основываясь на других элементах управления переделать контрол.

Пример(тут же и анимацию посмотрите):

```
<Style x:Key="button_ellipse" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="DimGray" Opacity="0.1"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"                          Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Height"                               Value="32"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"                  Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"                Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"                  Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Width"                                Value="32"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse"
                             Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                             Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                             StrokeThickness="0.25"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                                                        To="Black"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                                                        To="DimGray"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness"
                                                         To="0.5"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness"
                                                         To="0.25"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

С пользовательскими элементами управления сложнее, но гибкости у такого метода больше. Так что советую и с ним ознакомиться.

На моем опыте в 95% случаев достаточно было простого Style...

Comment: Ну вот как вы думаете я смогу переделать все контролы с картинки при помощи только Style? Меня больше всего пугает tabcontrol, progressbar и scrollbar, а вот всякие button и checkbox на легке я смогу переделать

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, вне всяких сомнений, всем необходимым функционалом стили обладают, что бы воплотить такие элементы управления. У таб контрола, прогресс бара, и скролл бара получаются довольно большие стили, и сложные для понимания новичку, но с опытом все придет. Я мог бы с вами поделится мною написанными стилями для TabControl и ScrollBar.

Comment: Еслиб вы поделились я очень был бы благодарен вам :)

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, [Вот](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LCBB/oASUsC5tc), в одном файле стили, в другом кисти для стилей.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, домой прийду и посмотрю )))

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, незачто, рад был помочь)

Comment: А вот ради интереса, вы не знаете как telerik делают свои контролы, первым или вторым способом, что потом они красиво лежат в dll? Ну если конечно знаете )

Comment: Они делают собственные элементы управления, насколько я знаю, но точно не уверен.

Comment: Я наверное уже запарил вас, а как это собственные, есть ли какие нибудь книжки об этом ? Очень просто интересно стало )

Comment: Я лично все узнавал методом проб и ошибок ) Но по первой же [ссылке](http://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread1132279.html) из поискового запроса нашел список неплохой литературы, о книге Мэтью Макдональда много хороших отзывов от друзей слышал.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за информацию, буду теперь читать :D

Comment: Почитайте Adam Nathan, WPF Unleashed. А вообще, у нас есть очень хороший список литературы по C#, неужели ничего из него не подошло?